# How to use reduce and the ramda "hex2color" function to count list of hex values than have r in their color name?

Tags: javascript, filter, reduce, ramda.js

"Use reduce and the hex2color function to count list of hex values than have r in their name";

My current attempt is below. The first piece I know needs to be fixed is the filter function. I need to be able to filter out any colors that have the letter "r", but cannot seem to find a way to easily fit that into the filter function. It could easily be a syntax issue as I think I am asking the filter to find any strings that === "r", even though I am trying to use "contains" to solve that and have it check the whole color word.

Once the filter function is working, I assume the next step is to simply use the reduce function, then compose them together. ( I could be way off off, however).

I am quite new to programming, any insight is extremely welcome. Thanks!!

```
const exercise3 = _ => {
    const hexes = ["#0000ff", "#f5f5dc", "#cd853f", "#663399", "#ffa500"];
    const letter = "r";
    const mapper = hex2color;
    console.log(map(mapper, hexes)); //blue,beige,peru,rebeccapurple,orange
    const filterer = el => contains(hex2color(el), letter);
    console.log(filter(filterer, hexes)); //yields nothing, I assume to using the filter wrong with "r".
    const reducer = (acc, el) => acc + 1;
    const mappedFn = map(mapper);
    const filtererFn = filter(filterer);
    const reducerFn = reduce(reducer, 0);
    const composedFn = compose(reducerFn, filtererFn, mappedFn);
    return composedFn(hexes);
  };
```

Comment: [From the docs](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#contains) it looks like you need to use contains(needle, haystack) but you're currently doing contains(haystack, needle)

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track, and the hint from James should help you along.  I want to note that `hex2color` has nothing to do with Ramda.  Also, although it should work, this is a strange use of `reduce`.  However any way to solve this problem with `reduce` would be slightly strange.  I guess what's meant is something like `hexes.reduce((acc, hex) => acc + (contains('r')(hex2color(hex)) ? 1 : 0), 0)` but I like your approach better, once it's cleaned up.  Even better would be to skip the `reduce` and just use `length`.